# Unauthorized al consumir recurso de Api Rest

Tags: .net, rest, restsharp

estoy intentando consumir un recurso de una API Rest, lo hago en .NET con la librería RestSharp.
El problema es que para recuperar todos los usuarios de la plataforma, no tengo ningun problema pues defino el recurso /customers/ y me los retornar todos.

```
public void GetCustomers()
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient($@"https://urlweb/api/v2/isp/realms/obj");
    var request = new RestRequest("/customers/", Method.GET);
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "password");
    var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request).Result;
    Customers customers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Customers>(response.Content);

}
```

Pero al recuperar un solo customer (el id:1 por ejemplo) del endpoint
https://urlweb/api/v2/isp/realms/obj/1 me retorna un 403 unauthorized, el método es como el anterior, solo cambiando el recurso:

```
public void GetCustomers(int idCostumer)
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient($@"https://urlweb/api/v2/isp/realms/obj");
        var request = new RestRequest($@"/customers/{idCostumer}", Method.GET);
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "password");
        var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request).Result;
        Customers customers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Customers>(response.Content);

    }
```

Alguien me sabe decir donde puede estar el problema?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo debía añadir una "/" al final del recurso...
No sé el motivo, pero me ha funcionado.

```
 RestClient client = new RestClient($@"https://urlweb/api/v2/isp/realms/obj");
        var request = new RestRequest($@"/customers/{idCostumer}/", Method.GET);
```